# Submiting solution to CodeChef shows wrong answer when results are correct. Why?

Tags: c#

Original task: You are given a number N. Find the sum of all numbers from 1 to N. Input: First-line will contain the number N. Output: Print the answer in a single line. Constraints `1 ≤ N ≤ 10^9`.

```
Sample Input 1: 4
Sample Output 1: 10

Sample Input 2: 8
Sample Output 2: 36
```

This is my code attempt:

```cs
using System;
    
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {   
        // your code goes here
        double sum, N;
        N = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        sum = N * (N + 1)/2;
        Console.Write(sum);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I think my logic is right, but after submission it shows wrong answer. Why?

Comment: You are given a number N. Find the sum of all numbers from 1 to N.

Input:
First-line will contain the number N.
Output:
Print the answer in a single line.

Constraints
1≤N≤10^9
Sample Input 1:
4
Sample Output 1:
10
Sample Input 2:
8
Sample Output 2:
36

Comment: I think my logic is right, but after submission it shows wrong answer

Comment: Nice first question! Next time please add all the details into the question (I've already copied them there :) ), so that we don't have to "extra" ask you / the question feels incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct. I think the problem is with evaluation and given statement `Print the answer in a single line`. You are printing it on the line, but not adding "new line". So the "automated machine that checks if results are correct" doesn't know where to split results. Also waiting for input `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of code is not supposed to be there, it would break system from continuing.

What you should do, is:

```cs
using System;
    
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {   
        double sum, N;
        N = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        sum = N * (N + 1)/2;
        Console.WriteLine(sum);  //Changed to console WriteLine

        // Console.ReadLine(); // (remove this)
    }
}
```